# How can I craft my WHERE statement to filter for the first day of a dynamic range of 5 months based off of the current month?

Tags: sql

I have a simple WHERE statement to pull back the first day of the month in my current month.
For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1
WHERE date_column = DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, 0, GetDate()), 0)
```

If ran today(2021-04-05) would return 2021-04-01.

How can I modify this query to return a range of current, +4 months out?
So running it again today(2021-04-05) my new expected output would hopefully be (2021-04-01, 2021-05-01, 2021-06-01, 2021-07-01, 2021-08-01)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, I would approach this by getting the first day of the current month and then adding to that:

```
select dateadd(month, v.n, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
from  (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)) v(n);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d9d19120176b291dc1cb97606eacf71a) is a db<>fiddle.

I think that `datefromparts()` is a cleaner way of getting the first day of the month -- especially when compared to arcane date arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried incorporating your solution into my query, and unfortunately I'm doing something wrong. This is what I tried:

select *
from table_1
where date_column = select dateadd(month, v.n, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
from  (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4) v(n);

Should I use an exist function?

Comment: @klinn . . . There was a typo in the answer, but the SQL Fiddle was fine.